# Control spaces between grouped bars in a barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I would like to have a grouped barplot with matplotlib and I use code that I acquired from https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html. 
Unfortnunately the spaces between the bars are too small and the height of the figure is also too small. I had a look at different websites (like this https://python-graph-gallery.com/5-control-width-and-space-in-barplots/) but was not able to adjust the spaces. Can someone help?

Here is the screenshot of my current plot:

[image]

Here is the Juypter code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


labels = ['Control \n Method 1', 'Method without\n coordination 1', 'Control \n Method 2', 'Control \n Method 3', 'Control \n Method 4' , 'Control \n Method 5']
ed_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27, 3]
srdp_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25, 3]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.30  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, ed_means, width, label='ED')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, srdp_means, width, label='SRDP')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Optimality in %')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12)
ax.legend()



def autolabel(rects):
"""Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
for rect in rects:
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                textcoords="offset points",
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: The spaces between bar positions are solemnly determined by the overall space available divided by the number of bars. You can use a larger figure, or make the labels smaller.

Comment: @PeterBe To make the labels smaller, rotating them could be an option

Comment: Thanks for your answers ImportanceOfBeingErnest and JohanC. I tried to make the picture larger using 'plt.figure(figsize=(70,70), dpi=400)' but it did not work out.

Comment: "it did not work out" is not a useful problem description. (Note that 70 inch is larger than your screen, though)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks for your answer. Well, the command 'plt.figure(figsize=(70,70), dpi=400)' does not change anything. The figure looks still the same. I also tried 'plt.figure(figsize=(2000,2000), dpi=400)' but this also did not change anything

Comment: As commented, you would need to make sure the figure fits your screen. E.g. `plt.subplots(figsize=(13,8), dpi=100)` should work.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the new command does not change anything regarding the basic plot. The figure still looks like the one I uploaded. The only difference is that Jupyter now also displays a second plot with empty content. When I want to save the figure by using the command 'plt.savefig('Methods_Test.png', edgecolor='black', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')' only the empty plot is stored.

Comment: In that case you are not running the exact code shown in the question - with the proposed modification of adding `figsize=(13,8), dpi=100` as arguments to `plt.subplots()`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Ah okay thank you. My mistake was, that I added an additional command instead of using the inital plt.subplots() command. Now it looks good. Thanks for your help